# Open Source Shopping Cart / Checkout System Like FoxyCart

Tags: php, web, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I'm looking for an open-source shopping cart check-out system like FoxyCart. The idea here is that I'm looking for a shopping cart and checkout only and *NOT* a shopping cart with a CMS. I have my own CMS that I love and I don't want my products managed by my shopping cart.

I'm open to any programming language.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As of now there isn't any stand-alone Cart + Checkout Open Source system that solves the requirements that FoxyCart does.

You will have to find a work around existing e-commerce platforms or DIY.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst not open source [Moltin](https://molt.in) might be worth looking into, you can use whichever components you need. It will require some extra work integrating with your CMS and frontend however.